# Windows Server 2008 SBS Standard: Routing and Remote Access - No internet

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-sbs

I just replaced the NIC adapter and now we can't use the new adapter's IP address as gateway at XP/Win7 clients, no internet access.

[Using Windows Server as a NAT Router](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/using-windows-server-nat-router.html)

**I cannot add WAN NIC, Remote Access contains only LAN NIC!**

Comment: I just disabled and re-enabled/set, now it's OK.